# Trading View Alert Delays

Tags: tradingview-api

For some reason, my TV alerts are seriously delayed. I have tested community Pinescript indicators as well as TV indicator alerts - both are significantly delayed. Any advice for a non-coder?

Logged out of TV on all devices, then logged back in.
Reduced number of alerts.

Comment: Why not ask whoever maintains that API for help? Without sharing any code, this looks pretty off-topic to me

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.